# Remove all annotations(MyPointAnnotations) where type != something

Tags: swift, mapkit

I want to remove all annotations (MyPointAnnotations) where type != "sport"

```
class MyPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var identifier: String?
    var time = Date()
    var creatorId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var type: String?
}
```

I saw a stackoverflow post to remove all annotations where title == someString. But I have no idea how to achieve my goal.

Stackoverflow

```
let filteredAnnotations = view.annotations.filter { annotation in
  if annotation is MKUserLocation { return false }// don't remove MKUserLocation
  guard let title = annotation.title else { return false }// don't remove annotations without any title
  return title != "sport"// remove those whose title does not match search string
}
view.removeAnnotations(filteredAnnotations)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the annotation is `MyPointAnnotation` and the type is not `nil`

```
let filteredAnnotations = view.annotations.filter { annotation in
    guard let type = (annotation as? MyPointAnnotation)?.type else { return false }
    return type != "sport"
}
```

Consider to use less optionals. Optionals are not an alibi not to write an initializer. If each annotation has an identifier and a type declare both properties as non-optional.